# Convert String to Decimal in pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, decimal, data-conversion, varchar2

I want to convert a string to a number with one decimal place.
Ex:

- 4     after conversion ->  4.0
- 4.1   after conversion ->  4.1
- 04.1  after conversion ->  4.1
- 04.0  after conversion ->  4.0

I have tried

SELECT TO_NUMBER('04.0','99.99') FROM dual;

But it will not convert the string to decimal number. instead it convert to a integer (4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But it will not convert the string to decimal number. instead it
>   convert to a integer (4).

Not really. The format of the number displayed is purely client dependant ( SQL * plus / SQL Developer etc ) and has nothing to do with how Oracle internally stores your numbers, which depends on the precision you specified for that column.

In order to see numbers in your desired format regardless of the client and assuming your territory's decimal separator is `'.'`( `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` is `'.,'`), you may simply use `TO_CHAR`

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('04.0','0D9') FROM dual;
4.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes it should be 
    SELECT TO_CHAR('0.1', '0D9')FROM dual;
Otherwise it will result 0.9 as .9 after the conversion

Comment: @ThilinaDeSilva : You're welcome and thanks for confirming. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you may try the TO_CHAR

SELECT TO_CHAR('04.0','99.9') FROM dual;

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes it should be 
    SELECT TO_CHAR('0.1', '0D9')FROM dual;
Otherwise it will result 0.9 as .9 after the conversion

Answer (score 0):

Declare the number varible like this

```
number(4,1);
```

Example:

```
declare
  pizza   number(4,1);
begin
  pizza := 4.1; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(pizza,'0D9'));
end;
```